# error jython when running command "mvn clean package"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jython

I am facing the following error when I run the maven command `mvn clean package`. The error is :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:27 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-03T14:03:55+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.sf.mavenjython:jython-compile-maven-plugin:1.4:jython (default) on project core-ism-engine: Jython failed with return code: -1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :core-ism-engine
```

Comment: Have you re-run Maven with the -e switch and have you read the linked article like it says in the error?

Comment: Run with `mvn clean install` and check.

Comment: finally, i remove jython-compile-maven-plugin:1.4 in.m2 folder and update maven again, and in run. btw thx all.